# Change <div> to <a>

Tags: jquery

I am a novice jQuery student and need a bit of help. Is it possible for Jquery to change a `<div>` to  an `<a>` dynamically depending on what the class of the `<div>` is? I have searched and can't find any reference to doing something like this using .add(), .append() or .html()

For example I want to change this:

```
"<div class="item"><div class="caption">pic1</div></div>"
```

to this:

```
"<a class="item" href="#"><div class="caption">pic1</div></a>"
```

Thanks for any help you may give or advice.
Mike

Comment: `<div>` elements aren't valid inside `<a>` elements.

Comment: Not valid, but it works and if you got existing code to work with you often have to compromise;)

Comment: instead of changing the DOM, add a click event to the div objects.  $('div.caption').click(function() { /* do something */ });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you check out jQuery [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)
They should be able to do what you like.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [`jQuery.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). You will probably want to use that in conjunction with [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Another option would be to use the manipulation functions to get the children of your tag, unwrap the tag, and then wrap the children with the desired tag.

```
jQuery('.item').children().unwrap().wrap('<a></a>');
```

However, as Andy pointed out in the comments, a `div` cannot exist inside of an `a` tag. That is not semantically correct HTML. What benefit are you trying to derive from doing this?

---

**Edit:** I saw you changed your question as I was updating my answer. Seems like you'd be better off with doing something like this instead (Different version mentioned by Silkster):

```
jQuery(document).delegate('.item', 'click', function (e) { /* Do something here */ });
```

[`jQuery.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: I am trying to integrate a jQuery lightbox, Yoxview into a coverflow like image gallery called ContentFlow  http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/. I need only the "active" center image to open in a lightbox when clicked, not every image. Clicking on any other image moves it to the center active position. It seems if I use "<a href>" for the images, every clicked image opens in the lightbox, not just the center one, so I was trying to think of a way for jQuery to alter the active image into a link. With other lightboxes, I have used ".addclass" to the "<div>" and it will open but not yoxview.

Comment: @Mike: Check to see if Yoxview has an `open` method or something to that effect. You could then use that to dynamically decide what you'll actually be opening. I use Shadowbox (http://www.shadowbox-js.com/), personally, and it has an open function that works very nicely.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I have successfully used Shadowbox in this configuration in the past. I will check Yoxview's API.

Answer (score 1):

So, yeah, it is possible ... you should be able to use a selector by class like:

```
$('div.item')
```

... to the update using the replaceWith() like:

```
$('div.item').replaceWith('<a class='item'></a>');
```

... and then for the content you can just get the content and updated later using the each function like:

```
$('div.item').each(function (){
     var divContent = $(this).html();
     $(this).replaceWith('<a class='item'></a>').html(divContent);
});
```